# DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable 'TempTable'

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, exception

I'm getting the following error whenever my code creates a DataTableReader from a valid DataTable Object:

"DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable 'TempTable'."

The thing is, if I reboot my machine, it works fine for an undetermined amount of time, then dies with the above. The code that throws this error could have been working fine for hours and then: bang. you get this error.
It's not limited to one line either; it's every single location that a DataTableReader is used. Also, this error does NOT occur on the production web server - ever.

This has been driving me nuts for the best part of a week, and I've failed to find anything on Google that could help (as I'm pretty positive this isn't a coding issue).

Some technical info:

DEV Box:
Vista 32bit (with all current windows updates)
Visual Studio 2008 v9.0.30729.1 SP
dotNet Framework 3.5 SP1

SQL Server:
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition- 9.00.4035.00 (X64)
Windows 2003 64bit (with all current windows updates)

Web Server:
Windows 2003 64bit (with all current windows updates)

Any help, ideas, or advice would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE 1:

Ok - Have tried the following now with no success:

1: Rebooted
2: SFC / ScanNow
3: Changed SQL Servers
4: Tried a different method that uses DataTableReaders
5: Cleaned solution

The only thing I did find that worked was copy & pasting the code
from the main Visual studio instance, into another which had a simple console app.
This then worked as expected (queried database and got results into a dataTable, created a datatablereader on that table, then queried hasrows before calling .Read()...
All of which worked.

I am struggling to see what could cause this, as there are NO code faults - i'm 100% certain, as it runs perfectly when published to the webserver.

Comment: (Assuming you have SQL server hosted locally) is your local drive low on space?

Comment: good question, and one I didn't check... but alas I have acres of free space on each drive (817GB to be precise)

Comment: I tried a colleagues recommendation of clearing out "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files" but it didn't exist in the first place.

I have now also tried removing the "HasRows" check and just do While(tr.Read()) and that still throws the same error.

Finally, to 100% eliminate the chance, I tried with a using block and still get the same error.

Comment: is it possible that your datatable, dt, is being changed elsewhere?

Comment: I don't have Reporting Services installed on the DEV box or the SQL box :/

Comment: No. It could theorhetically happen if two users hit the same code section at the same time, but I've only replicated this locally (so, just one user) and it happens whether or not the production site is running or not.

Comment: if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                iFolderID = (int)dt.Rows[0]["FolderID"];
            }  

works fine as an immediate replacement, but it's obvioulsy not great :/

Comment: Further experimentation has found that this isn't always solved by rebooting. However, building and deploying code that fails in this way on the dev machine, once deployed on any other machine works fine.

Comment: have now ran "sfc /scannow" and it didn't find any errors... trying to re-install 3.5 SP1, but hitting issues.

Comment: "marked as closed" because moderator removed relevant images in an edit that now make question look invalid.. nice :/ a comment explaining imageshack's demise would have been much better, as I could/would have updated this question to maintain it's relevance.. c'mon mods!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think using the while(reader.read()) may solve your problem.

```
if (myReader.HasRows)
   while (myReader.Read())
     Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", myReader.GetInt32(0), myReader.GetString(1));
else
   Console.WriteLine("No rows returned.");
myReader.Close();
```

**UPDATE:**
Also from msdn: 
The HasRows property returns information about the current result set. If the DataTableReader contains multiple result sets, you can examine the value of the HasRows property immediately after you call the NextResult method in order to determine whether the new result set contains rows.

Use the HasRows property to avoid the requirement to call the Read method of the DataTableReader if there are no rows within the current result set.

[DataTableReader.HasRows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I was under the impression that OP said it was the call to HasRows that was failing?

Comment: Correct. in your example, (myReader.HasRows) is the line that is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem and got rid of it after clearing the variables in the watch window.

Comment: `Clear Watch Window` actually resolved it... Weird!! Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Clearing the watch window & doing rebuilds worked for me.  However, because I had to remember to frequently rebuild, I eventually just renamed it also. (prior to renaming, adding additional watch variables on an object could cause previous watch variables on that object to become invalid -- even without progressing through the code, ie staying on the same line)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap usage of DataTableReader (and all IDisposables) with `using`.

Comment: that's not really going to help. I create the object, close the object and dispose the object.. as displayed in the code example above.

Comment: It is going to help to avoid other problems - if exceptions occurres before you close the reader it will remain unclosed. Using statements can help to avoid this.

Comment: That's not quite true. If it throws an exception and goes out of scope, then it'll get closed and disposed via the garbage collecton as normal. But yes, the using statement is the better way forward, and I normally use them. However, this code is "old" code written by another developer.. and it used to work fine. Thanks for the pointer, but what I'm after here is a solution to the problem detailed... Hope you understand :)

Comment: @Sk93: Yes, it will *eventually* get garbage collected, but in the meantime the connection will remain open.  At some point your connection pool is going to be overflowing.  Which might result in weird errors like you've seen.  The best practice is to use "using" on ANYTHING that implements IDisposable to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the 'using'

Comment: @Chris Lively: I completely understand this - in my own code, I would of course use "using" wherever practicle, for precisely the reasons you state. But this code works fine on every other machine it's been tested on. It has been running on a client machine almost continuously for over a year without fault (and is still continuing without fault). I cant see how this can have anything to do with connection pools, as this is only the second database connection made in the entire lifecycle of the product.

Comment: OK. To put this suggestion to rest: I have gone through the method and altered it to use "using" wherever it uses an object that implements IDisposable. I have also gone into to two methods it calls and done the same there - ALL connections, dataAdapters, DataTables and DataTableReaders within the callstack for this block of code are now written using "using" blocks.
I have also made this the first line of code called by the application as it starts up. Until this line fires, there have been zero connections to the database ..... and the problem persists exactly as described.

Answer (score 2):

OK.. Further down in the code, I have the following code:

```
using (DataTableReader tr = dtCustomers.CreateDataReader())
{
    ....
}
```

If I change this to read:

```
using (DataTableReader tr2 = dtCustomers.CreateDataReader())
{
    ....
}
```

Then, and remember this bit of code is much later down in the same procedure, BOTH bits of code work without fault!

So, this doesn't work:

```
using (DataTableReader tr = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    ...
}

....

using (DataTableReader tr = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    ...
}
```

But this does:

```
using (DataTableReader tr = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    ...
}

....

using (DataTableReader tr2 = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    ...
}
```

I don't understand why this way works, but it does and as I've not had another answer, I'll be going with this.

If you know why this works, and why the original doesn't, please can you enlighten me? :)

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would post on here in case it's helps someone else.  I tried a number of things and in the end i simply changed the name of the datareader and it worked, kind of similar to here.  i dont know why for sure but i think it might be because the datareader (originally) wasnt being closed, so maybe after a few times debugging, there was lots of "stuff" in memory with a certain name attached and it said "no more!".  still, i could be talking bullpies.  my advice, change the name of your datareader variable and make sure you close it after you use it

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for the post. I think the post however would be better suited for a comment rather than an answer. Have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), it might help.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug on getting the tableReader... i have code that has been working for ears and if i change another method sometimes i get that errro... some times it's solved just recompiling (rebuild), another times i reinstalled the .NET framework or use the option repair of it... i am starting to put try catch sections to use the reader if the system "wants" to givme the reader and the DataTable if not.
Greetings.