# System.InvalidOperationException: DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I deserialize a DataTable object from an XML file which works fine and the DataTable preview in Visual Studio displays the one row that it should contain.

However, when I create a DataReader on the table object like so:

```
    repository.SearchBaskets_dataReader = dataTable.CreateDataReader();
```

and attempt to read from it like so:

```
    while (repository.SearchBaskets_dataReader.Read())
                { //BLAH BLAH }
```

I get a strange error, which I didn't always get:

```
    DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable 'BasketOrders'.
```

Any ideas?

Let me re-emphasize that this bug started appearing without any changes in code.

Comment: hi, not exactly the same question but you can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446201/datatablereader-is-invalid-for-current-datatable-temptable

Comment: Yep no help from there. Due to design constraints, I do not wish to use the foreach on Rows. Actually solving this issue would also be great, as googling has not revealed anything yet.