# moq returning dataReader

Tags: moq, idatareader

I'm having a strange experience with moq/mocking.

Im trying to mock the data going into a method so that i dont have to have adatabase available  at test time.

So im loading in some data ive previously seralised.
Loading it into a dataTable, then creating a data reader from there, because my business layer method expects a data reader.

Then creating a mock for my data layer. and setting the return value for a particular method to my new datareader.

I am then setting (injecting) my mock data layer into my business layer so it can do the work of returning the data when the time comes..

```
var dataTable = DataSerialisation.GetDataTable("C:\\data.xml");
IDataReader reader = dataTable.CreateDataReader();

var mock = new Mock<IRetailerDal>();
mock.Setup(x => x.ReadRetailerDetails("00")).Returns(reader);

retailersBusinessLayer.RetailerDal = mock.Object;

var r = retailersBusinessLayer.GetRetailerDetail("00");
```

Now.. when the "GetRetailerDetail" is called is basically gets to "while(data.Read())" and crashes out but only sometimes.
I get the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable 'Table1'.
```

Othertimes it move past that and can read some columns data, but other columns dont exist. (which must be to do with my serialisation method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this isnt exactly a satisfactory answer, but the code works now..

its similar to this.. in that no reason was found.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446201/datatablereader-is-invalid-for-current-datatable-temptable)

Anyway... as stated above the issue was ocuring inside my GetRetailerDetail method, where the code hits **while(data.Read())** it throws the error..

The fix.. change the name of the data reader variable.. i.e. its was "data" and its now "data2".. thats all i changed.