# C# Excel DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable 'Sheet1'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446201/datatablereader-is-invalid-for-current-datatable-temptable) seems not helping me.

What I want to do is to read a excel .xlsx file contents to replace values of some cells and return the new file contents to the client. But the original file should remain as is. I don't want to save the new file to the system - it's not a solution.

Here is the code:

```cs
string excelFilePath = this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Test.xlsx");
var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(excelFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
Excel.IExcelDataReader exReder = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileStream);

System.Data.DataSet dataSet = null;
using (exReder)
{
    dataSet = exReder.AsDataSet();
}

if (dataSet == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot Make Data Set");
}

dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray = new[] { "Microsoft", "Test", "ASP.NET" };
bool hasChanges = dataSet.HasChanges(); // true

dataSet.AcceptChanges();
bool hasChanges2 = dataSet.HasChanges(); // false

var dataReader = dataSet.CreateDataReader(dataSet.Tables[0]); 
TextReader textReader = dataReader.GetTextReader(1); // 1 is ordinal no matter what I pass it throws an exception
byte[] results = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textReader.ReadToEnd());

return this.File(results, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

I am using http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ package

`dataReader.GetTextReader(1);` always throws an exception. How to make this text reader?  Or just get the bytes after the change?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Microsoft provided Excel.Interop .net libraries. They are natively designed to perform these functions. Here's a [dotnetperls blog](https://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) on this:

Comment: Already tried with Excel.Interop. When making an instance like: `Application xlApp = new Application()` it throws an exception: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).`

Comment: is this part of an asp.net project?

Comment: Yeah this is MVC. I found that for using Excel.Interop I must add permissions to IUSR from IIS in Windows Configuration.

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong here then, I read elsewhere that using Interop on IIS is bad news exactly with that error you posted. Can you debug and breakpoint on that line and check to see if your dataReader is populated?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I found a workaround with http://epplus.codeplex.com/ .